# Update to a particular revision in SVN?

Tags: svn, svn-update

I performed an `svn co -r XXX ...`. I deleted a file and then [accidentally] performed `svn up`. That updated to HEAD, so I lost my changes at XXX.

Is it possible to perform an update against a particular revision? If so, how?

Related, it is possible to undo the update to HEAD so I go back to XXX + local revisions?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `svn update -r <old revision number>`

Comment: Damn... it works. And the man page does not list `-r` as an argument to update (I checked before asking)... I also had to manually `cp xxx.ccp.min xxx.cpp`, but that was easy enough.

Comment: seems like it does not update the external link